# Devise forgot password renders wrong template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Rails 6, Devise 4.7.3   I have a forgotten password template in my views as users/passwords/new.html.erb that renders fine, collects an email, and sends that back to the Application. I also have a nice view template at users/passwords/edit that I am expecting to render when the email is sent in. In my case however, the template comes from devise/passwords/edit.html.erb which is not the one that should render.

Why is the devise template rendering and not the one I am expecting to run?

My routes:

```
 devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_in', to: 'users/sessions#new'
    get 'sign_up', to: 'users/registrations#new'
    get 'forgot_password', to: 'users/passwords#new'
    get 'reset_password', to: 'users/passwords#edit'
  end
```

In the end, all I had to do to get MY controllers working was to add the devise_for :users route to point to { passwords: 'users/passwords' }

Answer (score 0):

Since the devise controller is handling the password change it renders the default devise views.
You can either update the devise views with your own design or create your own `update_password` method to overwrite the default one from devise.

You can read more on how to implement your own update password method here: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Comment: I am not understanding that. When I provide an email, and click "Send me reset instructions", I get the email, and the link in that email is to:  users/password/edit? with the token... so the controller action GET edit should run.. but it runs the devise template not mine?

So it goes from Users::PasswordsController#new  to Devise::PasswordsController#create and finally Devise::PasswordsController#edit  when I would expect Users::PasswordsController...   WHY is the wrong controller being hit?

Comment: @DavidLazar Check your routes.rb file for devise generated routes. Devise will generate it's own routes that point to devise views. 
You can either modify those routes or just customize the dives views with your desired changes. See: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-views, and  https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#configuring-routes.

Comment: Fair enough.. but it is so hard to understand WTF devise is doing.. my routes are pretty simple... and do not work, 

    devise_scope :user do
        get 'sign_in', to: 'users/sessions#new'
        get 'sign_up', to: 'users/registrations#new'
        get 'forgot_password', to: 'users/passwords#new'
        get 'reset_password', to: 'users/passwords#edit'
      end

For some reason, it all falls apart with the link in the email to /users/password/edit... I have no idea how to teach devise to render my template not its

Comment: I figure it out. just had to add the devise for users to point to my controller. Thanks